# Finding the most ideal spot on a canvas to write text

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on a project where I have an canvas with an image drawn onto it. What I'm trying to achieve is to automatically position this text to a place on the canvas where it won't be bothersome for the contents of the image.

Small example: Say I have a canvas with the image of a group of people drawn onto it. In that case I'd like to position the text to a place where there are no faces, etc, so the text will be clearly readable and the image will won't be bothered by the text.

So far I made the following function in JS to draw the image onto the canvas:

```
    function drawStuff() {
            var slideBackground = new Image();
            slideBackground.src = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/50987/money-card-business-credit-card-50987.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb";
            slideBackground.onload = function() {
                canvasContext.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                canvasContext.drawImage(slideBackground, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            }
        }
```

Now my idea was to go over each pixel, see what hex color it has and check for a space with only that (or slighty differentiating) hexes, but I figured that wouldn't be very efficient.

Is there a cleaner/easier solution to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a full solution but it shows some pre-steps to get to a point where you can start to group pixels together. When grouped, find the bounds of each group and pick the one best suited for the application.

The steps here are:

- Draw in original image in grayscale using built-in filter
- Set blending mode to `difference` and draw blurred on top (the latter also using the built-in filter). This will filter away the high-frequency areas which tends to be (but not always) the area of focal interest.
- Iterate each pixel using a threshold to mark the darkest pixels using 32-bit signed arrays
- Optionally apply post-blur
- Then you would need to implement the functionality to group pixel areas (see topic [blob detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection) - I do believe the [Firefly metaheuristical algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_algorithm) / [PSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization) can be used here as well; even [marching square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) to some extent (see isobands in article)) and calculate bounds from there.
- Tip: since new elements would be relatively loosely placed, the image can be processed at a low resolution. The bounding box can be be scaled back up to final resolution.

*[image: idea] An alternative approach (untested, just a thought) is to use edge detection and segment the picture into cells, for example 9 by 9 to complement rule of thirds. Count number of pixels in each cell and use the less crowded (in terms of pixel count) areas or less crowded group of cells.*

For example, in the example image you link to, the upper and bottom left groups could be good candidates to place other elements (center is usually also the center of attention in many images, as well as [rule of thirds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thirds) - this can be useful information to further assist choosing a location). There are of course things like facial recognition, deep neural networks (for shape detection) and so forth - it all depends on how advanced you want it to be and how far you're willing to go! :)

The demo below, simple compared to the possibilities, depends on browser support for the new filter property (Firefox, Chrome should do fine at least). This saves you the trouble of manually implementing these filters unless you want to support older or non-conforming browsers - and they also have performance advantage.

Some tweaking of blur radius and threshold may need adjustment per image basis, or tested across a series of images to find an "ideal" value, but of course, I haven't taken upon me to do this here (ie. blur radius and threshold below is fully arbitrary).

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"), img = new Image;
img.onload = analyze; img.crossOrigin = "";
img.src = "//i.imgur.com/KCLeihX.jpg";

function analyze() {
  c.width = this.width;
  c.height = this.height;
  
  // draw original as grayscale
  ctx.filter = "grayscale(100%)";
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  
  // blur and grayscale for next draw as well as use difference blending mode
  ctx.filter = "blur(30px) grayscale(100%)";
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "difference";

  // draw again to produce difference
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  
  // mark pixels of interest
  var idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height),
      data = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer),
      i = 0, len = data.length;
  
  while(i < len) {
    if ((data[i] & 0xff) < 5) data[i] = 0xff0000ff;
    i++
  }
  
  ctx.putImageData(idata, 0, 0);

  // analyze concentrations/blobs here, use the bigger one...
}
```

```css
body {margin:0} #c {width:100%;}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

The pixels are shown in red above for clarity, but normally you would end up with a black-white matte such as in the result from the image below.

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"), img = new Image;
img.onload = analyze; img.crossOrigin = "";
img.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/10dGm.jpg";

function analyze() {
  c.width = this.width;
  c.height = this.height;
  
  // draw original as grayscale
  ctx.filter = "grayscale(100%)";
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  
  // blur and grayscale for next draw as well as use difference blending mode
  ctx.filter = "blur(30px) grayscale(100%)";
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "difference";

  // draw again to produce difference
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  
  // mark pixels of interest
  var idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height),
      data = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer),
      i = 0, len = data.length;
  
  while(i < len) {
    data[i] = ((data[i] & 0xff) < 5) ? -1 : 0xff000000;
    i++
  }
  
  ctx.putImageData(idata, 0, 0);

  // redraw with blur
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  ctx.filter = "blur(9px)";
  ctx.drawImage(c, 0, 0);

  // analyze concentrations/blobs here, use the bigger one...
}
```

```css
body {margin:0} #c {width:100%;}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

**Original:**

[image: original - family]

**Processed:**

[image: Processed]

Anything not fully black can be included for blob + boundary calculation.